# Sort ArrayList<HashMap> using Comparator with different different criteria

Tags: android, arraylist, sorting, comparator

I have one ArrayList in which I am storing values like **CustomerName, Type, Distance, State and using this ArrayList to show the ListView.**
I have created one comaprator in which I am sorting Customer on the basis of their type like below.

```
Type1 - Gold
Type2 - Silver
Type3 - Other
```

I am successfully done with the sorting but there is one more thing I have to add which I am explaining with example as below.

**EXPLANATION :-**

In my app we are having **premium user as type of Gold & Silver**. Other type of user are non premium user. I have the Web Services to get the data when user do some search from my app. Its based on **State, City and the Readius(i.e. Distance like 25miles/50miles, etc.)**.

For example you searched for **New Jersy(State/Province), Mahwah(City) & Radius as 25miles**, so it will give you list of available result based on these criteria. Now what happen is that in this search some of the out state result are also included because that satisfy the **Radius Criteria**. Like if I search for this I also get the result of **New York(State/Province)**. The problem arises here because in the State of New York I have some Gold type user and because of this the CustomerName of NewYork state go to top of NewJersy Silver type user.

**Result from Web Service call =**

```
CustomerName - ABCD
Type - Silver
State - New Jersy
Distance - 1mile

CustomerName - DEF
Type - Gold
State - New York
Distance - 20mile

CustomerName - XYZ
Type - Gold
State - New York
Distance - 22mile

CustomerName - PQR
Type - Other
State - New Jersy
Distance - 5mile
```

**After Sorting with My Comparator Rsult =**

```
CustomerName - DEF
Type - Gold
State - New York
Distance - 20mile

CustomerName - XYZ
Type - Gold
State - New York
Distance - 22mile

CustomerName - ABCD
Type - Silver
State - New Jersy
Distance - 1mile

CustomerName - PQR
Type - Other
State - New Jersy
Distance - 5mile
```

**What actually I want as a Result =**

```
CustomerName - ABCD
Type - Silver
State - New Jersy
Distance - 1mile

CustomerName - DEF
Type - Gold
State - New York
Distance - 20mile

CustomerName - XYZ
Type - Gold
State - New York
Distance - 22mile

CustomerName - PQR
Type - Other
State - New Jersy
Distance - 5mile
```

**My CRITERIA is -> I want to show the List of Premium user on the top of list for which user search (i.e if you search for New Jersy than show all the premium user of that State/Provice on the top) and than if OUT STATE (i.e. if New York state data is coming in the given radius) premium user and on the bottom rest of Other (no matter which state data it is) type of user.**

Comparator -

```
public class VendorTypeComparator implements Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>{
    List<String> preDefinedOrder;

    public VendorTypeComparator(String[] order) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        // order is {"Gold", "Silver", "Other"}
        this.preDefinedOrder = Arrays.asList(order);
    }


    @Override
    public int compare(HashMap<String, String> o1, HashMap<String, String> o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return preDefinedOrder.indexOf(o1.get("VendorType").toString()) - preDefinedOrder.indexOf(o2.get("VendorType").toString());
    }
}
```

Please kindly provide your suggestion to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you also separately state the sort criteria you are looking for ? ( like state > type > radius).

Comment: Basically i want that if you search for New Jersy state than all the premium result of that state should come first and below that other state premium result and rest is Other type. The reason behind this is that the premium user of the New Jersy (Gold/Silver) pay us to show their name on top if someone search for that state and if we show out state name on top then it will be not good for the business.

Comment: The idea is very straight forward that on top of list I want to show the IN STATE premium user whether Gold/Silver type and than OUT STATE premium user and for the rest Other type of user are on bottom.

Comment: You mean Split results into _gold/silver_ and _others_. Further split _gold/silver_ part into _in-state_ and _out-state_. Sort both _in-state_ and _out-state_ parts by type (gold first, silver later) and recombine them with _in-state_ first and _out-state_ last. Finally you append the others part (again sorted by state).

Comment: SO, you will need to split the results.

Comment: I am also thinking for the same but how I can recombine? Let say first I am sorting on the basis of Instate and Premium and storing in the list. Than again for outstate with premium and finally combining it. But is it feasible solution?

Comment: This approach can never be as good as a well thought and custom tailored algorithm, but at least this can get things done with less code. Have three lists: in-state, out-state and others. Feed main list to a _splitter_ function, and fill up these lists. Sort these lists, and combine in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible trick is to establish a metric based on a rank function. It will allow you to use **just your comparator, without any split/merge**.

Devise a function that maps an individual search result into a number.

- Say, give 10 million to any gold one in the target state, 9 million to
  any silver there, 8 to the golds in other states or whatever your
  logic. ABCD will get 10M rank; DEF and XYZ - 9M each.
- Then subtract the distance. ABCD will get 10M-1; DEF 9M-20, and XYZ - 9M-22. And so on.
- That will split your results into comparable groups and establish a finer order within
  those.

Have your comparator compare the result of the calls on o1 and o2. If zero, compare something else, e.g, the name, lexicographically. That's it.